# Cloudinary images associated to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am trying to find documentation on how to associate images uploaded through cloudinary to a particular user that will allow deletion etc by the user that uploads them, but not by other users.  However the images should be available to view publicly at all times.  I'm relatively new to rails however essentially I am trying to replicate using cloudinary:

```
class Image

  belongs_to :user

end

class User

  has_many :images

end
```

Obviously the code is not complete just trying to show the association I'm trying to achieve, if this is a suitable way of representing the relationship.  If anyone has suggestions for a better solution or can point me in the direction of some documentation that deals with an issue like this it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you use CarrierWave with Cloudinary for managing uploads of your Rails model. You need to define an uploader class and mount it to your Image class. Assuming your Image model class has a 'picture' attribute:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  version :thumbnail do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end

end


class Image

  belongs_to :user

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

end
```

Each user has multiple Image records, each holding a reference to an actual image being uploaded. For embedding such an image:

```
<%= image_tag(user.images[0].picture_url) %>
```

Or a thumbnail:

```
<%= image_tag(user.images[0].picture_url(:thumbnail)) %>
```

See [Cloudinary documentation](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration#carrierwave_upload) for more details.

Regarding image deletion: your web application probably allows users to manage images. Simply deleting an Image record would automatically delete the remote image uploaded to Cloudinary. For example:

```
user.images.last.destroy
```